# How to find the angle $x$ using the law of sines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

> [image]

I'm trying to find the angle $x$ using the law of sines. The equalities I found are given below

$$\dfrac{\sin (16)}{|AD|} = \dfrac{\sin (x)}{|AB|} \tag{1}$$

$$ \dfrac{\sin (14)}{|DC|} =  \dfrac{\sin (14)}{|DB|} = \dfrac{\sin (152)}{|BC|}\tag{2}$$

Could you assist me to take it from there?

Comment: You aren't using all the data.  What about the $32^\circ$ and $16^\circ$ angles?  Also, note that $\angle ADC = 208^\circ - x,$ and $208 = 180+2\cdot 14;$  I haven't done the problem, but there's a lot of suggestive relations here.

Comment: @saulspatz I used $16$ angle but did not use the angles in ADC.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's suggestive that $32=2\cdot 16.$  I should have been more explicit.  Also, I should have asked, are you *required* to use the law of sines?  Why not the law of cosines?

Comment: @saulspatz Indeed, I'm unable to see the difference between law of sines and law of cosines. And we can apply law of cosines when we know all sides (Perhaps I'm wrong with that).

Comment: @saulspatz Any possibility that this triangle can be solved using only law of sines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|BC|=a, |AB|=c, |AC|=b,$ and $|BD|=|CD|=d.$  In $\triangle BDC,$ we have$$
\begin{align}
{\sin152^\circ\over a} &= {\sin14^\circ\over d}\\
{\sin(180^\circ-28^\circ)\over a} &= {\sin14^\circ\over d}\\
{\sin28^\circ\over a} &= {\sin14^\circ\over d}\\
{2\sin14^\circ\cos14^\circ\over a}  &= {\sin14^\circ\over d}\\
a&=2d\cos14^\circ\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

We see that $\angle A = 104^\circ,$ so in $\triangle ABC,$ we have $$
\begin{align}
{\sin104^\circ\over a}&={\sin30^\circ\over b}\\
{\sin(90^\circ+14^\circ)\over a} &= {1\over2b}\\
{\cos14^\circ\over a}&={1\over2b}\\
a&=2b\cos14^\circ\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2),$ we have $b=d.$

That means that $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles, and it's easy to work out the angles around point $D.$  I get $x=134^\circ$ (on the second try, thanks to Lance.)

Comment: What law did you use?

Comment: The law of sines, and some trig identities.

Comment: But could we equate all the sides $1$? And I noticed that you made a relation with sides, not angles. Why is that?

Comment: @Enzo What do you mean by "equate all the sides $1$?"  Do you mean, "set all the sides equal to $1?$"  All which sides?  We have $|AC|=|DC|$ and you set them both equal to $1$ if you want to.  Why did I do that?  Because $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply $b=d.$  What else would I do?

Comment: Suppose we have that ${a\over d} = {\sin14^\circ\over \sin 152^\circ}$

Comment: @Enzo Please edit your comment so I can read it.

Comment: Take a look at it again

Comment: That's equivalent to what I wrote.  Why does it matter?

Comment: But you didnt write $\sin(x)$ anywhere. Can't we directly solve it for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86336/discussion-between-saulspatz-and-enzo).

Comment: Proving $\triangle ADC$ is isosceles is the key step. Good job. Final result should be $x=134^\circ$.

Comment: @Lance.  Thanks. I have no idea what I did before.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Sine law only approach.

WLOG, let $|AB|=1$.

$\sin x=\cfrac {\sin 16^\circ}{|AD|}$

$\cfrac{|AD|}{\sin 32^\circ}=\cfrac {|AC|}{\sin(360^\circ-x-152^\circ)}$

$|AC|=\cfrac {\sin 30^\circ}{\sin 46^\circ}$

From above, we have

$\sin x=\cfrac{\sin 16^\circ \sin(-x-152^\circ)\sin 46^\circ}{\sin 32^\circ \sin30^\circ}=\cfrac{2\sin 16^\circ \sin(x-28^\circ)\sin 46^\circ}{\sin 32^\circ }=\cfrac{\sin(x-28^\circ)\sin 46^\circ}{\cos 16^\circ } \tag 1$

expand $\sin 46^\circ$ doesn't seem to give any neat equation. Anyway, paul's solution is neat and insightful, except there is a minor arithmetic issue. Final result should be $x=134^\circ$.

---

I got stuck here until I realized how to solve this from solving a similar problem.

$(1)\iff \cfrac{\sin x}{\sin (x-28^\circ)}=\cfrac {\sin 46^\circ}{\sin 74^\circ} \iff \cfrac{\sin x+\sin (x-28^\circ)}{\sin x-\sin (x-28^\circ)}=\cfrac {\sin 46^\circ+\sin 74^\circ}{\sin 46^\circ-\sin 74^\circ}$

$\iff \cfrac{2\sin(x-14^\circ)\cos 14^\circ}{2\cos(x-14^\circ)\sin 14^\circ}=\cfrac{2\sin 60^\circ\cos 14^\circ}{2\cos 60^\circ\sin(-14^\circ)}$

$\iff \tan (x-14^\circ)=-\tan 60^\circ=\tan 120^\circ$

$\iff x-14^\circ=120^\circ \iff x=134^\circ$

It's implicit that $0<x<180^\circ$

Comment: Why do you use law of Sines and law of Cosines together? It makes it more complex.

Comment: Unless you can find the required quantities otherwise. How would you get $|AD|$? You can certainly represent $|AD|$ by another cosine law equation using $x$, but it could be more complicated to solve for $x$.

Comment: This can't be right... according to your result, $\cos\theta>1$ for $\theta$ real, which is not possible.

Comment: @Antinous. Right. Fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

$$BDC=180-2(14)=152\tag{*},$$

$$\frac{\sin(30)}{AC}=\frac{\sin(46)}{AB}\tag{1},$$

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{AB}=\frac{\sin(16)}{AD}\tag{2},$$

and by (*),

$$\frac{\sin(208-x)}{AC}=\frac{\sin(32)}{AD}\tag{3}$$

$$\overset{\text{by }(2)}\implies\sin(x)=\sin(16)\frac{AB}{AD}\overset{\text{by }(1)}=\sin(16)\frac{\sin(46)}{\sin(30)}\frac{AC}{AD}\overset{\text{by }(3)}=\sin(16)\frac{\sin(46)}{\sin(30)}\frac{\sin(208-x)}{\sin(32)}.$$
Now apply $\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y$ to obtain
$$\sin(x)=\sin(16)\frac{\sin(46)}{\sin(30)}\frac{\cos(x)\sin(208)-\cos(208)\sin(x)}{\sin(32)}.$$
$$\sin(x)\left(1+\frac{\sin(16)\sin(46)\cos(208)}{\sin(30)\sin(32)}\right)=\frac{\sin(16)\sin(46)\sin(208)}{\sin(30)\sin(32)}\cos(x).$$
Hence,
$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(16)\sin(46)\sin(208)}{\sin(30)\sin(32)+\sin(16)\sin(46)\cos(208)},$$
which gives $x=-46\implies x=-46+180=134$.

- All arguments in degrees.

Comment: great job! Where I failed to get through.  Could you elaborate on the final equation. That's where I got stuck. Thanks!

Comment: The step(s) from $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(16)\sin(46)\sin(208)}{\sin(30)\sin(32)+\sin(16)\sin(46)\cos(208)}$ to $x=-46$ is not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ is what puzzles me. Do you mean numerically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86389/discussion-between-lance-and-antinous).